# How to convert docx to pdf in laravel without losing its format and any other 3d party api

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-8, docx

How to convert docx to pdf in laravel without losing its format and any other 3d party API
I am using Dom pdf to convert word to pdf but every time I lose its format.

Answer (score 0):

Without the assistance of any other tool like PHPWord, for example, I think you are going to face the same issue each time, as most of the PDF libraries are based on wkhtmltopdf, the only responsability for these libraries is converting from HTML to PDF, so please consider using a different library as the one I mentioned before